# Python: How to call a dataframe from .py file to another py file without reading the dataframe for two times?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have below scripts (abc.py and xyz.py). The processing time to extract data from SAS to python is 5 mins. If I want to use the same data (df1) in xyz.py script, its reading again and taking 5 mins. So total time is 10 mins. Is there any way, if we can read the dataframe for once in abc.py and use the dataframe in xyz.py to avoid processing time.

```
abc.py
df1 = sas.sd2df('df_name', 'work') # it contains 1 50k rows

xyz.py
from abc import df1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle`. it allows to save/load a python object (a df for example) for using in various scripts .py

see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html

I didn't test it with a very big DataFrame but it may be quicker than reading your data two times